# Looping through multiple dataframes does not calculate properly

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I am attempting to perform calculations, then loop through the same pandas dataframe and perform the same calculation but with an altered variable (one that increases each time it loops). If the loop range is set to just 1, all rows calculate properly and the new dataframe is created. However, attempting to actually loop the program results in NaN values everywhere except the first row.

## Omega loop

```
for i in range(10):
    #Determine first and last Julian dates of data
    t1 = df.ix[:0,'jd']
    t2 = df.ix[n-1:,'jd']
    t2 = t2.reset_index(drop=True)
    tj = t2-t1    
    
    #Iterate over each observation within each star file
    jd = df['jd']
    dmag = df['dmag']
    
    sinw = np.sin(2*omega*jd)
    sum1 = sinw.sum()
    
    cosw = np.cos(2*omega*jd)
    sum2 = cosw.sum()
    
    #Calculate tau
    tau = ((np.arctan(sum1/sum2))/(2*omega))
    
    avgdmag = dmag.sum()/n
    
    
    #Calculate sample variance
    tot = (df['dmag']-avgdmag)**2
    tot2 = tot.sum()
    
    var = tot2/(n-1)
    
    #Calculate sums for power series
    sum3 = sum3 + ((dmag - avgdmag)*np.cos(omega*(jd-tau)))
    sum4 = sum4 + (np.cos(omega*(jd-tau)))**2
    sum5 = sum5 + ((dmag - avgdmag)*np.sin(omega*(jd-tau)))
    sum6 = sum6 + (np.sin(omega*(jd-tau)))**2
    
    #Calculate power series and normalized power series
    px = (((sum3**2)/sum4)+((sum5**2)/sum6))/2
    pn = px/var
    
    
    #Step through sequential frequencies
    omega = omega + (1/tj)
```

I also received a runtime warning from NumPy caused by the omega term at the end. I disabled "invalid" warnings as it was not causing an issue with the actual calculations. The first dataframe that incorrectly computes is `sinw` and `cosw`. And all subsequently calculated dataframes have NaN values.

Comment: for i in range(10): --- I dont see "i" in the loop.

Comment: I originally had it just print "i" so I could see the progress, but I don't need to use "i" in the calculations. Although, could I use my `omega` term at the end as a step size in the `range()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your `tj` is a pd.Series of length 1, not scalar as you would expect. After the first loop, `omega = omega + 1/tj` becomes a Series of length 1 (with 0 as index). Then in the 2nd loop, `tau = ((np.arctan(sum1/sum2))/(2*omega))` also becomes such a Series. When updating `sum3`, `jd - tau` (a Series of length `n` minus a Series of length `1`) gives you a Series with all `NaN` except at index 0 where both series match. After that all subsequent Series has lots of `NaN`s.

The solution is to calculate `tj` as a scalar, such as
`tj = df.loc[n-1,'jd'] - df.loc[0,'jd']` (assuming `n = len(df)`).

Anyway, your piece of code can be re-written for readability.

```
tj = df.loc[n-1,'jd'] - df.loc[0,'jd'] #tj is loop invariant
for _ in range(10):
    sum1 = np.sin(2*omega*df['jd']).sum()
    sum2 = np.cos(2*omega*df['jd']).sum()
    tau = np.arctan(sum1/sum2)/(2*omega)
    avgdmag = df['dmag'].mean()
    var = df['dmag'].var() #unbiased sample variance

    sum3 += ((df['dmag'] - avgdmag)*np.cos(omega*(df['jd']-tau)))
    sum4 += (np.cos(omega*(df['jd']-tau)))**2
    sum5 += ((df['dmag'] - avgdmag)*np.sin(omega*(df['jd']-tau)))
    sum6 += (np.sin(omega*(df['jd']-tau)))**2

    px = (((sum3**2)/sum4)+((sum5**2)/sum6))/2
    pn = px/var

    omega += 1/tj
```

Comment: Excellent. That worked flawlessly. Thank you for the help. Still a bit new to all of this, so the shortcuts and simplifications are good for me to learn and incorporate.